# Is there any constraint in resources to make REST calls within a stream().map() function?

Tags: java-8, stream

I currently have to develop an interface where, given a list of elements, I have to make a call to an endpoint for each one of them and then create an object with each of the responses. At the moment, there is no way to bundle all elements into one single call so I'm stuck with making it this way.

From a code perspective, the easiest way to do it is just doing this:

```
List<ResponseDto> responses = list.stream().map(element -> {
    ServiceResponseDto dto = httpService.callWith(element);
    return new MyResponseDto(dto.getInfo(), otherInfo);
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there any limitation or code smell on doing this? Another option would be using a forEach like in here:

```
List<ResponseDto> responses = new ArrayList<>();
list.forEach(element -> {
    ServiceResponseDto dto = httpService.callWith(element);
    responses.add(new MyResponseDto(dto.getInfo(), otherInfo);
});
```

But I don't see any difference in terms of resource utilisation and I'm just creating side effects in the forEach loop that can be avoided by just using the first approach.

Another thing to make the code faster would be to use `pararellStream` but my understanding is that I can starve the machine resources by creating to many threads that will be waiting for IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the steps in your first suggestion:

```
List<ResponseDto> responses = list.stream()
    .map(httpService::callWith)
    .map(dto -> new MyResponseDto(dto.getInfo(), otherInfo))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which looks a little bit cleaner. Remember that a Stream is lazy so you do not have to put all the logic in one map statement - there is no penalty.

Regarding your other question, yes - do not use the parallel stream for blocking IO calls, as it can hoarde threads in the common pool which could otherwise be used by other parallel streams.

There is a mechanism that will allow you to still utilize threads without necessarily blocking the common pool. Enter the `CompletableFuture`.

```
// imports elided, but all part of the JDK
ExecutorService fixedPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16); // choose a good number - could be numberOfProcessors * 2

List<CompletableFuture<MyResponseDto>> responses = list.stream()
    .map(element -> CompletableFuture
          .supplyAsync(() -> httpService.callWith(element), fixedPool)
          .thenApply(dto -> new MyResponseDto(dto.getInfo(), otherInfo)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// sequence futures so I only have to account for one future
CompletableFuture<List<MyResponseDto>> result = waitForAll(responses);

List<MyResponseDto> finalResult = result.join(); // try to put this code as late as you need it, since it will block the current thread

fixedPool.shutDown(); // also this, it will render the pool unusable anymore
```

The sequence function appears below. In functional programming, the sequence function transforms a `List<T<U>>` into `<T<List<U>>`. In this case `T` is the `CompletableFuture` and `U` is the data.

```
// sequence futures
public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> waitForAll(List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    CompletableFuture<Void> completedFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
    return completedFutures
        .thenApply(ignoreThis -> futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

We needed to re-implement the sequence function even though `CompletableFuture` has an `allOf` method because the return type of that is `CompletableFuture<Void>` (to cater for the fact that not all your `CompletableFuture`s might have the same type) so we hand-rolled our own given that our data is of the homogenous/same type.

Comment: For what I understand, using the `CompletableFuture` implementation I'm basically doing the same thing parallelStream would do but providing my own thread pool to avoid problems with other `parallelStream`s in the code. Is that correct? Would it make sense to use `parallelStream` in the case this is the only place where it is used? The biggest part of the time consumed by the async task is in IO. Wouldn't providing too many threads cause a performance impact because of all the context switching the processor would have to do just waiting? How can you know what's a good number?

Comment: It depends on how slow the IO call is. If the IO call is fast anyway, you can just use a parallel stream. If it is really slow - like 300 ms or more, and then you have around 10 items - that would be 3 seconds - then using a separate thread pool with a CompletableFuture might work better. There is another library you can use - Netflix's Hystrix - but I think that I like the CompletableFuture better - but it is a matter of taste.